# c++ pointer deletion inside function

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I know if I create a pointer in the header file, I should always delete it when the destructor is being called, but what about if I create a pointer inside of a function. I know basic variables get destroyed at the end of the block, is it the same for pointers?

For example:

```
Class::Function()
{
    int i = 3; // This gets destroyed after the function ends
    int* j = 5; // What about this? Do I have to delete it somewhere to keep from a leak?
}
```

If I initialize `j` inside of the constructor, I would say `delete j;` to prevent leaks, etc. Is there something I should do in this case?

Comment: If you didn't `new` it, don't `delete` it.

Comment: I downvoted because this question only shows that you have not studied enough how pointers work in C++. So, take it as a stimulus to study more.

Comment: If you don't allocate any memory in heap you don't have to worry

Comment: does it even compile?

Comment: In the embedded systems world, we assign addresses of hardware devices to pointers, in order to access the devices.  In these cases, there is no memory allocated, so `new` or `delete` are not used.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning `int` value to pointer

```
int* j = 5;
```

is illegal because you are storing `int` to `int*`. Anyway you can cast it

```
int* j = reinterpret_cast<int*>( 5 );
```

**but** dereferencing this pointer would lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), since you dont know where does that pointer point.

---

You should init pointers like that

```
int* j = nullptr;
```

Since `c++11` you cant create instance of `nullptr_t` and assign it.

```
nullptr_t initPointer;
int* j = initPointer;
```

---

If you dont use `new` operator to assign memory to pointer, you can't `delete` this pointer, it would lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Otherwise if you use `new` you need matching `delete` or you would get [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). If you want to check your program have memory leaks, check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730/what-is-the-best-free-memory-leak-detector-for-a-c-c-program-and-its-plug-in-d) and choose one tool. I can recommend [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Addendum: On a modern system with virtual memory, every process has it's own virtual address space. A pointer will be in the scope of the program, even if no actual storage has been assigned to the address. You don't have to worry about taking out the kernel. If you don't have virtual memory support for one reason or another... Cry havoc and let loose the frobweeszleqrrrtxzzt

Comment: Thank you for pointing out! Iam familiarized with logical to physical address conversion and paging, i dont know where I came to it :/ thank you. Fixed.

Comment: Sorry, but I have miscommunicated my point. Your initial wording was good. It just needed some expansion to cover the virtual memory case. What you described still happens with a great many systems.

Comment: No problem. I think ill leave it as it is, its described enough. Just its a really bad idea to assign integral to pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Every call to `new` needs a matching call to `delete`. If you have more `new`'s than `delete`'s, you get memory leaks. If the opposite, you get [double deletes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169774/what-happens-in-a-double-delete). In your case, if you never called `new`, then there's no need for delete!

There are tools out there to help match your new's and deletes. My personal favorite is [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/). It's super quick and easy to use, and it runs on the c++ source code! It generally does a good job at catching unmatched new and delete calls.

Comment: These days the language encourages you to avoid using new.